# How to close an activity from another activity

Tags: android, android-activity, activity-finish

I need to close activity. But not right after its on pause. I need to close it when I'm in other activity.

how can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this method too,

For Android Studio:

```
 ((Your Main Activity) Activity()).finish(); //this will close that corresponding activity
```

or

```
android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid()); //using this you can exit from the whole activity  for both Eclipse and Android studio
```

For Eclipse:

```
  finish();
```

Or

```
private void kill_activity()
   { 
  finish();
  }
```

Comment: thank you. I prefer using your first suggestion, but i have a problem. Eclips writing that there is not action like - getActivity. How do I manage this issue?

Comment: You are Eclipse that you didnt specify. That code using in android Studio.Just try that second method

Comment: i tryied the third options and i get the error: No enclosing instance of the type MainActivity is accessible in scope

Comment: i think for eclipse finish(); more to close a activity.Can you share your code

Comment: No Kiprin ,i just like to know, how you calling your finish ();.I hope while click on any button u need to close your activity. if so you just call finish();

Comment: ohh, im calling it just like you wrote - finish(); . but this action close the current activity im in and i cant find a way to controll which activity will close.

Comment: you are trying to call that finish() in a activty page(public class Activity Name extends Activity ) or else

Comment: public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        View exitButton = findViewById(R.id.exit_button);
        exitButton.setOnClickListener(this);}

Comment: public void onClick(View v) 
    {
 // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  
 switch (v.getId()) 
        {
          // More buttons go here (if any)...
               case R.id.exit_button:
         finish();
         break;

        }
    }

Comment: i dont think you understand what i mean. i will explain: i have 3 activities. im starting from 1 than im passing to 2 (without closing 1). form 2 im passing to 3 (and i close 2). at this moment i want to close activity 1 that left open.

Answer (score 0):

Just pass object of activity which you want to close to the activity from where you want to close it and do some thing like this `obj.finish();`

Answer (score 0):

you need to pass `context` of `activity`(that you want to close) to other activity and then you can call

```
(Activity(context)).finish();
```